# How to iterate over two strings simultaneously ksh

Tags: ksh

I'm using data that is returned by another person's ksh93 script in the format of a print to the standard output. Depending on the flag I give it, their script gives me the information I need for my code. It comes out like a list separated by spaces, such that a run of the program has the format of:

```
"1 3 4 7 8"
"First Third Fourth Seventh Eighth"
```

For what I'm working on, I need to be able to match the entries of each output, so that I could make the information print in the following format:

```
1:First
3:Third
4:Fourth
7:Seventh
8:Eighth
```

I need to do more than just printing with the data, I just need to be able to access the pairs of information in each of the strings. Even though the actual contents of the strings can be any number of values, the two strings I get from running the other script will always be the same length.

I'm wondering if there exists a way to iterate over both at the same time, something along the lines of:

```
str_1=$(other_script -f)
str_2=$(other_script -i)
for a,b in ${str_1},${str_2} ; do
  print "${a}:${b}"
done
```

This obviously isn't the right syntax, but I have been unable to find a way to make it work. Is there a way to iterate over both at the same time?

I know I could convert them to arrays first then iterate by numerical element, but I would like to save the time of converting them if there's a way to iterate over both simultaneously.

Comment: Arrays in korn shell have limited number of entries , but are convenient for this type of requirement. Apart from shelling out to awk or other tool, I can only think of arrays of equal length and iterate over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think it is not quick to convert the strings to arrays?
For example:

```
`#!/bin/ksh93

set -u
set -A line1 
string1="1 3 4 7 8"
line1+=( ${string1} )

set -A line2 
string2="First Third Fourth Seventh Eighth"
line2+=( ${string2})

typeset -i num_elem_line1=${#line1[@]}
typeset -i num_elem_line2=${#line2[@]}

typeset -i loop_counter=0

if (( num_elem_line1 == num_elem_line2 ))
then 
   while (( loop_counter < num_elem_line1 ))
   do
       print "${line1[${loop_counter}]}:${line2[${loop_counter}]}"
       (( loop_counter += 1 ))
  done
fi
`
```

Answer (score 1):

As with the other comments, not sure why an array would be out of the question, especially if you plan on referencing the individual elements more than once later in your code.

A sample script that assumes you want to maintain your str_1/str_2 variables as strings; we'll load into arrays for referencing individual elements:

```
$ cat testme
#!/bin/ksh

str_1="1 3 4 7 8"
str_2="First Third Fourth Seventh Eighth"

str1=( ${str_1} )
str2=( ${str_2} )

# at this point matching array elements have the same index (0..4) ...

echo "++++++++++ str1[index]=element"

for i in "${!str1[@]}"
do
    echo "str1[${i}]=${str1[${i}]}"
done

echo "++++++++++ str2[index]=element"

for i in "${!str1[@]}"
do
    echo "str2[${i}]=${str2[${i}]}"
done

# since matching array elements have the same index, we just need
# to loop through one set of indexes to allow us to access matching
# array elements at the same time ...

echo "++++++++++ str1:str2"

for i in "${!str1[@]}"
do
    echo ${str1[${i}]}:${str2[${i}]}
done

echo "++++++++++"
```

And a run of the script:

```
$ testme
++++++++++ str1[index]=element
str1[0]=1
str1[1]=3
str1[2]=4
str1[3]=7
str1[4]=8
++++++++++ str2[index]=element
str2[0]=First
str2[1]=Third
str2[2]=Fourth
str2[3]=Seventh
str2[4]=Eighth
++++++++++ str1:str2
1:First
3:Third
4:Fourth
7:Seventh
8:Eighth
++++++++++
```